# How to slide up and down on mouseover using CSS and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, slider, mouseover

http://www.sherpany.com/

Here is a site that I found. I was wondering how to make the "Investors, Board of Directors, Companies" section.

I want to know how to do it in pure css only, and another way using javascript? How can I make this happen, and also add the button, and make it disappear as it slides back down.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please demonstrate the code you have tried and ask a specific question in regards to the issue you are having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set two different classes and add some css transition:

let's say each 'block' has the **block** class and each button has the **button** class, then do something like :

```
 .block {
  height:40px;
  opacity:0.4;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.block:hover {
  height:100px;
}

.block > .button {
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.block:hover > .button {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Each transition is target at a css property.

Here's a little playground/example for you:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FLHmy

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. Would you by any chance know the javascript way?

Comment: Yes. If you use jQuery do something like : `$('.block').on('mouseover',function() { $(this).animate({opacity:1,height:'100px'},1000); $(this).find('.button').animate({opacity:1},1000); });` and `$('.block').on('mouseout',function() { $(this).animate({opacity:0.4,height:'30px'},1000); $(this).find('.button').animate({opacity:0},1000); });`

Comment: I added the javascript to the link you sent me, and it seems to not work when I change the high or opacity inside the JS.

Comment: You need to remove the css (at least the ':hover' and 'transition' parts). Do you have any JS error ?

Comment: I do, it just says "unexpected error."

$('#js .popUp').on('mouseover',function() { $(this).animate({opacity:1,height:'100px'},1000); $(this).find('#js .popUp').animate({opacity:1},1000); }); and $('#js .popUp').on('mouseout',function() { $(this).animate({opacity:0.4,height:'30px'},1000); $(this).find('#js .popUp').animate({opacity:0},1000); });

Comment: don't copy/paste the 'and' between the two scripts ;)

Comment: Got it, how do I make it stop on the mouseover? It keeps animating as long as I am over it. I want it to slide up, then stop, and go back down when I mouseout

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [GSAP Animation](http://www.greensock.com/) platform. You simply need to link to it in the head section.

You would want to use a tween like so where #menu is a tab that you want to pop up.

```
TweenMax.to("#menu", .5, {height:____})
```

____ is whatever the new height should be.

You would also want

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0
}
```

inside of a relatively positioned div.

Answer (score 0):

For a pure CSS way of doing it, I'd look into the following:

- Hover: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)
- Opacity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity
- Transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Then make a few div's (or other block elements) and when the user hovers over element, change its height and opacity. If you set a transition on those styles then modern browsers will show a nice little effect.

For example:

```
.move {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    width: 100px;
}
.move:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 10px;;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkrehm/mn55L/

Keep in mind rendering optimization (especially on mobile devices) and fallback for older browsers. My example likely won't work on older versions of IE.

As for how to do it in JavaScript, I'd look into the .animate() function. http://api.jquery.com/animate/